# Airflow DAG Schedule Meaning

Tags: python, cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

What does the below airflow dag schedule mean?

schedule: "12 0-4,14-23 * * *"

Thanks,
cha

I want to schedule airflow dag to run run hourly but not between midnight and morning 7. Also, i want to pass more resources during last run of the day. so, I am trying to figure out how to do in airflow.  I usually schedule once a day at certain hour. I want to understand how to schedule multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cron expression. There are several tools on the internet to explain a cron expression in human-readable language. For example https://crontab.guru/#12_0-4,14-23_*_*_*:

"At minute 12 past every hour from 0 through 4 and every hour from 14 through 23."